# A swarm of locusts is being exterminated, find the formula for the population of locusts for t days

Tags: calculus

> A certain region was attacked by a swarm of locusts. The function $g$,
>   defined by $$g(t) = a \cdot e^{kt+1}$$ with $a$ and $k$ being real
>   constants, gives the value, in thousands, of the number of locusts $t$
>   days after the swarm started being exterminated.
>
> a. Determine the exact values of $a$ and $k$, knowing that two days
>   after the first count, which revealed there were 20000 locusts, 6000
>   had died.

I did:

$$20 = a \cdot e^{2k+1} \Leftrightarrow 20 = a \cdot e \Leftrightarrow a = \frac{20}{e}$$

(Note that I used 20 and not 20000 because the formula expresses the results in thousands)

My book says that is correct.

Now, to find the value for $k$ I did:
$$14 = \frac{20}{e} \cdot e ^{2k+1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{14}{1}}{\frac{20}{e}} = e^{2^k}\cdot e^2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{14e}{20}}{\frac{e^2}{1}} = e^{2^k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{14e}{20e^2} = e^{2^k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{14}{20e} = e^{2^k} \Leftrightarrow \\\log_{e^2}{\frac{14}{20e} = k}$$

But my book says that $k = ln{\sqrt{0.7}}$. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'd say you over-complicated things. By expressing e^2k as an exponent of an exponent, you may have confused yourself. You are not far from the answer

Comment: Did you mean to write $e^{2^k}$. That is not the same as $e^{2k}$. Can you explain your reasoning going from $e^{2k+1}$ to $e^{2^k}\cdot e^2$.

Comment: @IanMiller I realised earlier that's what I did wrong. It was just a distraction that caused me a big confusion

Comment: I was meaning the difference between $e^{2^k}$ and $e^{2k}$. Not the error with $e^2$ vs $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this makes it clear.

$$14 = \frac{20}{e} \cdot e ^{2k+1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{14}{1}}{\frac{20}{e}} = e^{2k}\cdot e \Leftrightarrow \frac{14}{20} = e^{2k} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{0.7} = e^k \Leftrightarrow \ln \sqrt{0.7} = \ln{e^k} \Leftrightarrow k = \ln{\sqrt{0.7}}$$

Comment: I see I did $e^{2^k}\cdot e^2$ instead of  $e^{2^k}\cdot e$. Thanks

Comment: You correct answer should have $e^{2k}\cdot e$ not $e^{2^k}\cdot e$.

Comment: @IanMiller What caused me the confusion was that $e^{xy} = (e^x)^y$. I forgot to add the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $e ^{2k+1} = e^{2k}\cdot e $ you can write

$$14 = \frac{20}{e} \cdot e ^{2k+1} \Leftrightarrow 14 = 20 \cdot e^{2k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{14}{20} = e^{2k} \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{ln}0.7 = 2k \Leftrightarrow k = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{ln}0.7 \Leftrightarrow k = \operatorname{ln}(0.7^{\frac {1}{2}})$$

Instead of going this way, that is more error prone:

$$14 = \frac{20}{e} \cdot e ^{2k+1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{14}{1}}{\frac{20}{e}} = e^{2^k}\cdot e^2$$